# Apache VirtualHosts based on host header field

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost

I am trying to configure apache2 to have the following virtualhosts:

- One that serves requests for www.mydomain.com
- Another one that servers requests for anything else

How do I go about doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Have a `NameVirtualHost *:80` directive, and define both `VirtualHost` blocks as `<VirtualHost *:80>`
2. Put your "anything else" vhost first in the config (or alphabetically first in an included directory) with any ol' `ServerName` - it'll get all requests that don't match the other host - and your vhost with `ServerName www.mydomain.com` second.

That's all!

Comment: I've done what you said, but the anything else vhost is getting requests for www.mydomain.com.

Comment: Are you sure the vhosts match the `NameVirtualHost` exactly?  Please post your config.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/iG6Sr6fy. I'm trying to redirect anything that is not for mydomain.com to mydomain.com.

Comment: Hrm - not 100% sure if this is required (I've never tried without one), but try adding `ServerName something.something.something` to your `000-default` vhost.

Comment: Straight from the Apache documentation: `If you are using name-based virtual hosts, the ServerName inside a <VirtualHost> section specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to match this virtual host.`

Comment: @gman I'm not sure what you're getting at.  This is also straight from the Apache documentation: `If it finds one, then it uses the configuration for that server. If no matching virtual host is found, then the first listed virtual host that matches the IP address will be used.`

Comment: In any case, @DanieL, I've verified that lacking a `ServerName` in your first-loading vhost causes that vhost to serve all requests, effectively undoing the `NameVirtualHost` directive.  Add that and you should be good to go.

Comment: @Shane Madden Read it again, and you'll see that Name-based virtual hosting requires `ServerName` to be set. It was in response to your comment prior to mine. The Vhost for www.mydomain.com should come first, with the wildcard vhost defined last to catch everything else.

Comment: @gman Huh?  The first vhost, not the last one, is the one that catches all other requests.

Comment: The way I write my Apache configs, explicit definitions come first (higher priority), and wildcard "catch-all" vhosts come last as the lowest priority since they are generic.

Comment: @gman To clarify, are you talking about a vhost with a `ServerAlias` with a wildcard definition?  That's just fine to have last, but the vhost catching *unmatched* hostnames always must load first.

Comment: Thanks Shane, adding a `ServerName` to the wildcard vhost did the trick.